# ssh'd-to terminal background becomes white only from WSL2

Tags: ssh, colors, wsl2, mutt, color-theme

I read email with `mutt` on an Ubuntu 18 host, which I ssh into.
When I ssh from macOS 11 (via iTerm2, if that matters) or from another Ubuntu 18 host, all is well.

But when I ssh from WSL2 (running Ubuntu 18, 20, or 22), mutt's colors are wrong.  The top and bottom lines remain ok, but the list of emails has changed from bright grey on black to bright grey on white, almost unreadable.  Ditto for viewing one email: the background has become white.

No `color` directives are in the `~/.muttrc`.  But when I add, e.g., `color normal red black`, then the bright grey text becomes red (as it should), but the background does not become black (my choice has been overridden).  That override happens only from WSL2, not from macOS or Ubuntu.

Even weirder, when I choose a nonblack background color there (cyan, brightblack, brightyellow, etc.), the background color *does* change from WSL2 (and from the others).  Black is special.

For WSL2 versus the others, the outputs of `set` and `env` differ only in SSH_CONNECTION, SSH_CLIENT, SSH_TTY, XDG_SESSION_ID, and ephemera like OLDPWD, LINES, COLUMNS.
In particular, TERM is always `xterm-256color`.  So I doubt that mutt knows whether or not it's come from WSL2.  So the misconfiguration is likely not in mutt, but in WSL2.

In WSL2, no change happens when I adjust rightclick > properties > colors > four radio buttons for colors, or properties > terminal > checkboxes for separate foreground/background colors.

How can I stop WSL2 from overriding the default background color to white?
Might something other than mutt also provoke this behavior?  (Not vim:  in all cases, its solarized8 theme and syntax coloring renders fine.)

Comment: My *guess* is that this has nothing to do with WSL and everything to do with the terminal you are using to access it.

Comment: Does WSL give me a choice of terminals?
Or, if you mean `$TERM`, why would the same value for that work from mac and ubuntu but fail from WSL?

Comment: The terminal is what is actually rendering your "stuff".  Not WSL.  WSL is only sending the commands and the terminal is doing the work.  The standard terminal invoked by cmd.exe is one terminal, the [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-us&gl=US) is another with more features.  Git BASH invokes MINGW64 terminal (yet another).. there are many.  The behavior of the output is controlled by the terminal itself.

Comment: Actually.. using a quick test, cmd.exe and windows terminal will fire up bash.exe (wsl) but MINGW64 hangs doing who knows what :P  Also, I like the terminal provided by MobaXTerm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal is what is actually rendering your "stuff". Not WSL.

WSL is only sending the commands and the terminal is doing the work.

The standard terminal invoked by cmd.exe is one terminal, the [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-us&gl=US) is another with more features.

Git BASH invokes MINGW64 terminal (yet another).. there are many.

The behavior of the output is controlled by the terminal itself.

Comment: I installed Windows Terminal from your link. From instances of that I launched various wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-xx.yy's. From those, mutt worked normally.